# TeamCity not compiling Scala with IntelliJ IDEA runner

Tags: intellij-idea, teamcity

We have been using TeamCity for years now. A couple of days ago we updated to the latest version (2018.1 (build 58245)).

We noticed builds are not compiling Scala code (using IntelliJ IDEA project runner with the exact same settings we had before). It does compile the java side, but completely skipping Scala files, so we end up with an empty jar basically. The build doesn't fail and none of the tests or reports are being taken into failure consideration as they are not being compiled at all.

We are also facing Java 1.6 issues, but right now we urgently need the Scala stuff fixed.

Note: Same exact projects are being compiled with IntelliJ IDEA just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please watch for this ticket in our tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-56061

Comment: @PavelSher well, that’s my ticket that I opened under my company’s name after not finding answers anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression. It will be fixed in 2018.1.1.

Comment: And that’s when?

Comment: Next week, likely on Monday

Comment: Is rolling back an option for users, @PavelSher?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with TeamCity Professional 2019.1.2 which is way past 2018.1.1. Any idea?

Comment: @Gnana if you still have this problem, I suggest to post it to our forum. Initial issue was fixed and the customer who experienced it confirmed the fix in 2018.1.1. Your problem can be different and we'll need to dig into details. It's easier to do in our forum: https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366709-TeamCity-General-Topics

Comment: @PavelSher Sure will check again and if needed discuss it in the teamcity forum. We are also in the process migrating all our projects to SBT instead of just keeping it as an IDEA project.